# How do i get an input of time in milliseconds?

Tags: android-studio, time, android-edittext, long-integer

```
private long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
private long TimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
```

i have declared these variables, which is meant to store an input from an EditText, but in my `OnCreateView` i have this line

`START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = edtInsertTime.getText();`

but it gives me an error, how do I get the input of time in milliseconds and store it in `START_TIME_IN_MILLIS`?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post the error you received, and that would be helpful since it can be of hundred reasons..

Just looking at this code, you have variable of type long, ( which is a numeric type ), and what you get from edtInsetTime.getText()? , a type "Editable" according to the documentation, and you can't store Editable object in a long variable.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText

```
public Editable getText ()
Returns Editable - The text displayed by the text view.
```

To get a long value from it, you first need to get a String from this EditText, then convert it to a long format, and then assign it to the variable.

Examplary code would be.

```
START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = Long.valueOf(edtInsertTime.getText().toString());
```

Breaking it down.

String  text = edtInsertTime.getText().toString()
returns the String value of an edittext

That value then can be converted to a long value by parsing the String to long, with methods like

```
Long.parseLong(text)
```

or

```
Long.valueOf(text)
```

Asking this question means you don't have basic understanding of how types works in java, so feel free to read about it https://www.baeldung.com/java-primitives